# Questions with "What" followed by "a/an"

Tags: grammar

I am asking for an explanation/description when to use "a/an" after "What" in a question, or why to omit "a/an".

When we are asking a general question we use "what" as a determiner:

- **What films do you like?**
- **What university did you go to?**
- **What dog do you have ?**

I am wondering that there is no use of "a/an".
For example :

**"What a dog do you have" or "What a film did you watch ?"**

Right now, i haven't found any information about this.(google,dict,grammar rules,study-books)

Comment: You can construct declarative statements using "what" and "a" together, e.g. "What a beautiful day" and "What an amazing view"

Comment: "What kind of dog do you have?"  "What kind of film did you watch?"

Comment: Would it be absolutely incorrect to say:  "What a dog do you have ?" ? That´s my question basically.

Comment: @FrankMK: Yes, absolutely incorrect.

Comment: @FrankMK: _Was für ein Hund_ = What kind/breed/type of dog?

Comment: It *would* be correct to say "What a dog you have!"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The "What" in the beginning of the question doesn't affect whether or not you should use "a" or "an."  Grammatically speaking, the determining factor in whether you should use "a" or "an" depends on the word FOLLOWING the "a/an."  For instance, you would use "a" if the next word started with a vowel (some exception, i.e. words that don't have a vowel as a first letter, but produce a vowel sound as the first syllable).  Example: "What A wonderful day" or "What AN awesome day."  Also, I feel like this thread should be bringing to attention the varying usage of "what" versus "which."  It seems they're both getting thrown around interchangeably...

Comment: Yes, now there is light :-)

Comment: You've confused _what_ as an interrogative and its use with exclamatory sentences.

Comment: This does not explain why there isn't an article in questions beginning with "What", and "which" e.g. *What doll would you like to buy?* No article. *Which book would you like to read?* *"Which orange do you want?"* and *"What time is it?"* No articles. Why?

Comment: I’m very surprised that this was selected as the correct answer, because it does not even attempt to address the actual question. The difference between _a_ and _an_ is not relevant to the question at all, nor is the difference between _what_ and _which_. The question is why interrogative _what_ is never followed by indefinite articles in, and this answer doesn’t deal with that at all. @FrankMK, did you mean to accept Karl’s answer (which does address and answer the question) rather than this one?

Comment: Ok. Both answers, from KarlG and Laura Rys turned on the light in my understanding and the wrong way I was looking on that.  But here it isn't possible to check 2 Answers. So I decided to be gentle. Looking on the rules of a/an  E.G What a dogs do you have..doesn't work well.

Comment: @ Janus, if you think to check Karl's answer, for reason of clarity for other users, let me know.

Answer (score 4):

The interrogative (question word) *what* functions as a [determiner](http://www.linguisticsgirl.com/the-interrogative-determiner-in-english-grammar/) in such questions, which means that an indefinite article, also a determiner, cannot be used.

This might seem clearer in a sentence where the *what* doesn't come at the beginning and the answer is already known:

> You want *what* topping on your ice cream? *"What's wrong with pickle relish?"*
>
> You want *a* topping on your ice cream? *"What toppings do you have?"*
>
> You want *this* topping on your ice cream? *"No, I want that one."*

*What* performs the same determinative function as *a* and *this*. You only need one of these words to let someone know what topping you're talking about.

Exception: in the idiom

> What the hell is going on here?

*the hell*, although *the* is also a determiner, only functions as an interjected intensifier and doesn't affect the grammar of the sentence.

What may have confused you is that when *what* is used to begin an *[exclamatory sentence](https://www.englishpractice.com/improve/exclamatory-sentences-verb-patterns/)*, the indefinite article will *always* come after *what* if the following noun is singular:

> What a total mess! *"What mess?" he asked, kicking through a pile of newspapers and a tin can.*
>
> What a great looking car! *"What car? I don't see one in the street."*
>
> What a stupid mistake I've made! *"What mistake did you make?*
>
> What a beautiful bouquet of roses! *What roses? Those are carnations.*

When the noun is plural, the noun has no article:

> What gorgeous flowers!

Comment: Yes, now there is light :-)